# How to get a middle section to scroll overflow using Flexbox in an Angular application

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I have an Angular application, where after looking at 100s of flex examples, I just cannot get the section I want to scroll. It is an Angular application, but this is more a question on Flexbox.

I have replicated as close as I can what I have, and it has the same problem [here on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-scoll-problem?file=src/app/app.component.css)

So, what I want is a wizard sort of application, where I have buttons always at the bottom, and I swap in different components.

So this is setup in `app.component.html` ....

```
    <div id="outer-container">    
        <div id="router-outlet-parent">
             <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>  
        <app-buttons></app-buttons>
    </div>
```

The pages are routing into `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` and we can see the fixed buttons in `<app-buttons></app-buttons>`...

[image]

Now I have a component (Page1), that has two bit, a "header" (gray) and a "contents" section that will not fit (in the pink).

What I want is to scroll the **pink** section, and NOT the header.

If I set `overflow` to auto  in the following (app.component.css), I get the whole component scrolling (including the gray header)

```
    #router-outlet-parent {
         flex: 1 1;
         overflow: auto;
            /** min-height: 0; **/
    }
```

If I set the above to `overflow: hidden`; then it no longer scrolls, but I just cannot get the pink section to scroll, ie the section `#main-scrolling-content` as in `page1.component.css`.

How can I do this with this setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css rule to your form in page1 component

```
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: thankyou! This seems to do exactly what I am after. Trying to understand why this works... my understanding is so it needs `form 100%` so it does not grow past the bounds of it's parent container (I don't know why any element EVER does this, but they just do) - but not sure why it needs to be flex too - but it does otherwise it does not work (everything I think I am getting layout/flex, I disappoint myself). Anyway, thankyou.

Comment: Elemet's height is `auto` by defoult, so it grows to it's content. So we bounding form to it's parent heght. Then make form flex with column direction to layout it's children verticaly and make `.main-scrolling-content` become flex item so it fills all free space. Without flex we would calculate height of `.main-scrolling-content` like `calc(100% - 20px)` where 20px is header height. But we must have header fixed height. With flexbox it becomes more, you know, flexible :)